# How to use quote characters python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently opening CSV files using the following:

```
with open('cweapons.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    COMMONWEAPONS = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
```

One of the fields contains commas which are to be printed and not seen as the start of a new set of data. For example:

```
Sword,1,2,"A really, Really big sword"
```

This gives 4 sets of data. I know I'm supposed to used quotechar='"' but I'm unsure of the syntax or where to put it. Where/how should I specify the quote character to get the desired result? Does the system see " as a quote character by default? If not, what does it use by default?

Thanks

Comment: You should use `newline=''`, but *normally*, the `csv.reader()` comes configured to recognize quoted values like that ootb.

Comment: The default dialect is `excel`, which should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it [defaults](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) to `"`. If you want to change it, use keyword arguments (like this example from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)):

```
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
```

Note you'll also want `newline=''` in the event there are newlines in the quotes (as per [this footnote](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3)).